# can i install ubuntu as a second operating system on an empty second partition without having to download to a disk first

Tags: downloads

I have have divided my HDD into two partitions. On C, I have Windows 8, partition E is empty. I have downloaded Ubuntu onto a flash drive. How do I transfer it to drive E and be able to boot up to choose which operating system I want to use?

Comment: You might need to burn the iso onto a disk - not a flash drive

Answer (score 0):

The following information is taken from the Ubuntu help center (presuming that you're burning the iso onto a disk):

1. Proceed with installation until you are asked this question: "How do you want to partition the disk?".
2. Choose "Manually edit partition table".
3. Listed will be your current partitions.
4. Select the partition you want to resize and press Enter.
5. Select "Size:", press Enter.
6. Select Yes, press Enter.
7. Type in a new size in gigabytes for your partition, it's recommended you free up at least 10 GB of free space for your Ubuntu install. Press Enter when happy with your changes. It may take some time to apply the changes.
8. Create a swap partition of at least your amount of RAM (if you don't know, 8000 MB is a good value).
9. Create a partition for your Ubuntu installation.
10. Create other partitions if necessary: see [DiskSpace](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace)
11. Select "Finish partitioning and write changes to disk".